# Filtered index seek for `is NULL` condition and scan for opposite

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, filtered-index

Assume there is a table like:

```
create table #data (ID int identity(1, 1) not NULL, Value int)
```

Put some data into it:

```
insert into #data (Value)
select top (1000000) case when (row_number() over (order by @@spid)) % 5 in (0, 1) then 1 else NULL end
from sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2
```

And two indexes:

```
create index #ix_data_n on #data (Value) include (ID) where Value is NULL
create index #ix_data_nn on #data (Value) include (ID) where Value is not NULL
```

Data is queried like:

```
select ID from #data where Value is NULL
```

or

```
select ID from #data where Value is not NULL
```

If I examine query plan, I see that in first case index seek is performed and in the second case index scan is performed. Why is it seek in first case and scan in second?

**Addition** after comments:

If I create ordinary covering index instead of two filtered covering:

```
create index #ix_data on #data (Value) include (ID)
```

Query plan is showing index seek for both `is NULL` and `is not NULL` conditions, disregarding % of the NULL values in column (0% of NULLs or 10% or 90% or 100%, not matter).
When there are two filtered indexes, query plan is showing index seek for `is NULL` always, and can be index scan or table scan (depending on % of the NULLs), but it is never index seek. So, seems, essentially the difference is in the way condition 'is not NULL' handled.

It means, probably, that if index is intended for 'is not NULL' check only, then either normal index or filtered index should perform better and be preferred, isn't it? Which one?

SqlServer 2008, 2008r2 and 2012

Comment: look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829929/sql-server-does-not-use-an-index-comparing-datetime-to-not-null

Comment: Because the NOT NULL condition hit a tipping point where it's actually more efficient to use a scan (in your case it should be roughly 60% of the table).

Comment: If index is used only for querying data satisfying `is not NULL` condition, what index type is better, ordinary or filtered?

Answer (score 2):

The Seek vs Scan in query plans you are seeing is a red-herring.

In both cases, the query is being answered by scanning the appropriate non-clustered index from beginning to end, returning every row.

By examing the XML query plan, you can see that the index Seek predicate is "#data.Value = Scalar Operator (Null)" which is meaningless as every row meets that criteria.